# How to check even and odd from std_logic_vector for pixel

Tags: vhdl

I want to know that " I have 2 value which is `std_logic_vector` and I want to check its last bit for even and odd and I want both of them to calculate the exact position of pixel value. Can this will be possible through case statement".

```
X_cont : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)
Y_cont : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)
```

And I want to check only LSB.

Comment: Checking the lsb is easy: if x_cont(0) = '1' then

Answer (score 1):

checking both LSBs using case is:

```
  process(x_cont, y_cont)
    type res_t is (both_low, one_low, none_low);
    variable result: res_t;
    variable lsbs: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
  begin
    lsbs:=x_cont(0) & y_cont(0);
    case (lsbs) is
    when "00" =>
        result:=both_low;
    when "01" | "10" =>
        result:=one_low;
    when others =>      
        result:=none_low;
    end case;

end process;
```